# Getting error like this imap_open(): Couldn't open stream

Tags: ssl, gmail, imap, imap-open

I am trying to access my company mail id (the mail provider is Gmail) inbox using IMAP. I have applied almost all the possible solutions available here and also on google. But I am facing the same issue.

These are the some solutions which I tried,

1. allow less secure app access Gmail
2. enabled IMAP access from Gmail
3. added novalidate-cert

Here's **my code:**

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = 'mymail@company.ae';
$password = 'mypassword';

// try to connect 
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Tiriyo: ' . 
imap_last_error());
```

**Error message**

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX 
in \path\to\file\index.php on line 12
```

I don't see where I'm going wrong. Please help...

Comment: Check whether there's a firewall that blocks your connection completely.

Comment: This is not a firewall problem. I am encountering the same problem on my dedicated root server. When I test the connection with telnet, the connection is working as it should. Only imap_open don't want to.

~ # telnet imap.gmail.com 993
Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c07::6c...
Connected to imap.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Answer (score 2):

Google has deactivated the regular login for third parties on 2022-05-31!

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

It is now necessary to implement the Google PHP lib.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-web.md

The option for less secure apps has also been removed by Google, which now also eliminates this possibility.
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: They apparently also removed the PHP lib, they just redirected it to JS.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by generating an app-password for my application.

see: [How can I read emails with Google Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533029/how-can-i-read-emails-with-google-gmail)