# How can I read emails with Google Gmail?

Tags: php, gmail, php-imap

Google has turned off access to gmail from less secure apps. Therefore I cannot connect to gmail service with "php_imap" and read emails. Is there any way I can solve this? Or another solution I can use?

**My current link code is:**

```
$imap = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
```

Comment: You could use the GMail HTTP API, for example. Or use proper Gmail authentication in your front-end. Or use App Password, as mentioned by google: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cupdate-your-app-or-operating-system%2Cuse-an-app-password

Answer (score 3):

In your account settings - security, after enabling two-step verification, set an application-specific password, which you can use to replace the original login password

Comment: App Password unfortunately less secure apps don't work.

Comment: @ArifAkyol App Password does work, if you set it up correctly. Unfortunately you've given no details so we don't know what you may have done (or not done) or what specific error you're getting now. Update your question if you have more details.