# get gmail items to custom page

Tags: php, gmail, imap

**I'm trying this to get the sent emails from Gmail to my custom page.**
***I've added dummy Gmail credentials while checking please change with your real Gmail account***

How can I get the emails? This code isn't giving any errors but also not fetching any emails from the Gmail sent box.

```
    <?php




 /* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'adasd1231312@gmail.com';
$password = '**************';

//echo $hostname;

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password);

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');


// if emails are returned, cycle through each...
if($emails) {
  
  // begin output var 
  $output = '';
  
  // put the newest emails on top
  rsort($emails);
  
  // for every email... 
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    
    // get information specific to this email 
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
    
    // output the email header information
    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';
    
    // output the email body
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
  }
  
  echo $output;
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);




            ?>
```

Look forward to hearing from all of you guys.

Help me with this.

Comment: Almost everything is commented out, so there's nothing to fetch the mail.

Comment: thanks for noticing, updated the code, can you please help me now?

Comment: `//$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');` is still commented, so `if ($emails)` will always be false

Comment: Uncommented in my files and here as well.  I've added dummy Gmail credentials while checking please change with your real Gmail account. Still not working :(

Comment: I'm getting `imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX`. This could be related to gmail disabling insecure apps.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71613932/getting-error-like-this-imap-open-couldnt-open-stream

Comment: Has this ever worked? When did you first write this code? As anyber says it's only a couple of weeks since GMail changed the way you have to access their accounts from code such as this. Read the support article for ways you can resolve it: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: what if I try to get the same using my outlook account?

Comment: Have you tried printing out $emails?

Comment: Outlook has a similar "App password" mechanism as GMail now has, I believe. Should be more or less the same.